# Not able to run this activeX

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I am not able to run this -> http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_object active X on ie-7, on my other m/c (ie-7) it works. Any idea why? Is there anything I need to install?

PS: There is no error.

Comment: How would anyone here know? You haven't said what "not able to run" means, or given any idea of any error messages, or provided any information that would help solve your problem. Remember that we can't see your monitor from here; all we have to go on is the information in your question.

Comment: I liked your comment but not clever enough! Question edited to let you know what this means here... (Actually it was there before too)

Comment: @Vishal, you still didn't explain what "not able to run" means. Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: @Ken, There is a URL in the question if you open it with your IE you will see a slider control, got it! So, now my problem is that I see the control in one of my IE-7, for other it just displays a blank.

Comment: @Vishal, it's not our job to try and run your problem ActiveX. It's your job to describe the problem. And I don't use IE, so I couldn't open it with that even if I wanted.

Comment: @Ken: You can't open IE so you can't help out here but you can happily vote it to be closed? And I just asked why it's opening in one IE and not in other :) if any one has any idea! and gave the URL if people want to see what I am trying to open.

Comment: @Vishal: Yes. If this was a question about car mechanics, and you said "My car won't start. You can test drive one like it by going to this dealership.", would you expect me to go drive the car? If you ask a question about programming with an ActiveX, I expect you to describe the problem you're having; if I then want to go elsewhere to run the ActiveX to figure it out, I can. You still have not provided enough information to make this a question, IMO, and I still think it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Common Controls. eg [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=25437d98-51d0-41c1-bb14-64662f5f62fe&displaylang=en).

This is an old UI library sometimes used in HTAs. It was never intended—and is completely unsuitable—for use on the open web. It will more often fail or be blocked by default security settings than be usable, even in IE.

For W3Schools to be offering this as their default example for the `<object>` tag, and then to imply that only IE supports `<object>` is ludicrous. But then [this is far from their own howler](http://w3fools.com/).